# Exclude specific files from all dependencies in pom

Tags: maven

I want to exclude pdf files from all the dependencies. When I use filter property and specify the folder name for a pariticular dependency as below it works.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                      <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>com.test:myexample</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>TESTCASES/VFX/**/**/**/*.pdf</exclude>
                                    <exclude>Test/**/*.pdf</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>

                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.test.CLI</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

However it does'nt work, when  I used the configuration below. Reference link: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Do I need to follow any specific fileset pattern?

```
                 <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*.pdf</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the filter property as below it works.

```
<filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/*.pdf</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
```